# Sort view items by field collection's field value

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I added a field collection to Basic page that contains:

- box title
- box image
- box position on page

You can add 0 or more field collection's items to every basic page. Every node may contain 0 or more boxes. They will be used instead of default teasers. Here is an example:

***Node 1:***

- field collection item: [Title 1, image1.png, 3]
- field collection item: [Title 2, image2.png, 1]

***Node 2:***

- field collection item: [Title 3, image3.png, 2]

**Taxonomy Term View is configured as below:**

Format: unformatted list
Show: Fields

***FIELDS***

Field: The field collection

***FILTER CRITERIA***

Content: Published or admin

***SORT CRITERIA***

Field: box position on page (asc)
Content: Post date (desc)

***CONTEXTUAL FILTERS***

Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)
Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

However, items are sorted only by post date and "box position on page" field has no impact on sorting. I expect boxes to be sorted in this order:

- field collection item: [Title 2, image2.png, 1]
- field collection item: [Title 3, image3.png, 2]
- field collection item: [Title 1, image1.png, 3]

Note that 2nd box leads to Node 2 and the remaining to Node 1.

How to sort boxes by "box position on page" field that is part of field collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [field_collection_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module which it creates a default View of field collection type. Its address is `/admin/structure/views/view/field_collection_view` and I recommend you clone this View and configure the rest of the options. The *Fields* section contains a few items that are very helpful, like *Host Entity ID*, *Host Entity Type* and ... .

[image]